# Javascript regex, match all words before length limit

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a long title into different small parts. Each small part shouldn't exceed the limit of 10 characters and I cannot find a solution...
Currently, I'm trying with `/(.{10}\S*)\s/` but testing with `TESLA AND MICROSOFT AND ANOTHER WORD` it returns also the word that is included in the limit (**TESLA AND MICROSOFT** AND ANOTHER WORD) and I don't want it... I mean, the expected result should be **TESLA AND** that has less than 10 characters...
Is there a simple way to do it?

EDIT:
What I want to do, it to split a single-line text into multiple lines, and the line length shouldn't be greater than 10 characters if there are multiple words. If a single word is longer than 10 characters, should return the full word.
eg. `TESLA AND MICROSOFT ANDANOTHERLONGWORD AND OTHER LONGWORDS`

this text should be:

```
TESLA AND
MICROSOFT
ANDANOTHERLONGWORD
AND OTHER
LONGWORDS
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate and provide more examples? Do the white spaces count in the 10 characters? How about a word that has more than 10 characters?

Comment: Perhaps like this `(?<!\S)\S.{1,8}\S(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/XAQPjk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, tried to split with your example and I received: **[" ", " ANDANOTHERLONGWORD ", " "]**

Comment: And also the "negative lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers.

Comment: so you want ANDANOTHER LONGWORD to be split because of your criteria right?

Comment: What is the minimum length of the "words"?

Comment: @EugenSunic, not quite... 
This is what I want... if there are multiple short words to be in a single line o max length of 10, and the words that exceed the limit of characters should remain the same, without splitting it
TESLA AND,
MICROSOFT,
ANDANOTHERLONGWORD,
AND OTHER,
LONGWORDS,

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I don't think I need a minimum limit.. from what I said before, the short words should be pushed in a single line of max length of 10.. 
For example, is ok if I have:
I LOVE,
REGULAR,
EXPRESSIONS,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you want to use split, you can use a capture group to keep what is captured after using split.

As split might leave empty entries, you can remove them from the final result, and optionally use trim to remove the trailing spaces.

```
(?:\s|^)(\S.{0,9}|\S+)(?!\S)
```

- `(?:\s|^)` Match either a whitspace char or assert the start of the string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\S.{0,9}|S+` Match a non whitespace char and 0-9 times any char or match 1 or more non whitespace chars.
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right.

```js
const regex = /(?:\s|^)(\S.{0,9}|\S+)(?!\S)/;
[
  "TESLA AND MICROSOFT ANDANOTHERLONGWORD AND OTHER LONGWORDS",
  "I LOVE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS",
  "I",
  "TESLA AND MICROSOFT ANDANOTHERLONGWORD ANDANOTHERLONGWORD ANDANOTHERLONGWORD AND OTHER LONGWORDS"
].forEach(str => console.log(str
  .split(regex)
  .map(s => s.trim())
  .filter(Boolean)));
```

Comment: Almost there, but when I have multiple long words I got: **["TESLA AND", "MICROSOFT", "ANDANOTHERLONGWORD ANDANOTHERLONGWORD ANDANOTHERLONGWORD", "AND OTHER", "LONGWORDS"]**
The long words should remain untouched, but in different lines, because exceed the length limit

Comment: @OprisorValeriuVladut I have updated the pattern with some more examples

Answer (score 1):

You may try this one:

```
/(?!\s)(?:[A-Z\s-]{0,9}[A-Z]|[A-Z-]+)\b/mg
```

- `(?!\s)` make sure the first character is not a white space
- `(?:...)` non-capture group
- `[A-Z\s-]{0,9}[A-Z-]` any `[A-Z-]` character and spaces at length of 0-9, ends by `[A-Z-]`(eliminates spaces for both ends)
- `|[A-Z-]+` or a long word of any length with no spaces in between
- `\b` with a word boundary ahead

Check the [test results](https://regex101.com/r/WZaw4p/1/)

```js
const text = 'S-TESLA INSTALACOES INDUSTRIAIS EIRELI';

const regex = /(?!\s)(?:[A-Z\s-]{0,9}[A-Z]|[A-Z-]+)\b/mg;

console.log(text.match(regex));
```

Comment: Almost there, but is there a possibility to match all kinds of characters?
For example, I have: **S-TESLA INSTALACOES INDUSTRIAIS EIRELI** 
and the result is: **["S", "TESLA", "INSTALACOES", "INDUSTRIAIS", "EIRELI"]**

S-TESLA word shouldn't be split

Comment: Yes, that would be [`(?!\s)(?:[A-Z\s-]{0,9}[A-Z]|[A-Z-]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/WZaw4p/1/), just add the allowed characters in the `[A-Z]` set